# Facebook Messenger Bot curl_exec returns false

Tags: php, facebook, chatbot, messenger

hopefully you can help me.
I created a simple Messenger Chatbot yesterday and it works fine. Then I tried to program it more complex and the result was that I don't get any responses anymore.
I deleted and created a new Facebook App and I used a simple script again. But this script won't work either.

```
$hubVerifyToken = 'YES-THIS-IS-MY-BOT';
$accessToken = "MY-HOPEFULLY-RIGHT-ACCESS-TOKEN-I-RENEWED-IT-SEVERAL-TIMES";

if ($_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'] === $hubVerifyToken) {
    echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
    exit;
}

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];


$answer = "Error";
if($message == "hi") {
    $answer = "Hello";
}

$jsonData = '{
"recipient":{
    "id":"' . $sender .'"
},
"message":{
    "text":"' . $answer . '"
}
}';
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$accessToken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

I checked the $resp and I found out that it return 'false'?
But I have absolutely no idea why ...

Can you please help me?
Comment if you need more infos.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you maybe need a little more practice in how to debug problems. You had some working code, then you changed it, and it stopped working. Why did you then delete it all and start again? The better approach would have been to gradually undo your changes, one by one, until you found the change that caused it to fail. Then you come here and ask a single, focused question about that specific change (if you can't figure it out by yourself, of course).

Comment: I tried to undo all my actions. I tried to debug. Nothing worked for me. Then I came here and wrote a new question.

My specific question is, why curl_exec returns false? There is no reason for that behavior.

Comment: This is my point, just asking "why doesn't it work?" doesn't help anyone to help you. Presumably you had some similar code before, when it worked. What has changed between the working case and the not-working case? Have you tried using some other URL? What happens if you just try and hit something like 'google.com', do you get a response, or an error? What happens if you visit that URL in a browser? I don't know php, so can't give you an answer, but I'm trying to help you learn to do the basic debugging steps that any developer needs to be able to do, rather than just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: _“I tried to debug”_ - and what did that look like …? _“My specific question is, why curl_exec returns false?”_ - well don’t ask _us_, ask _cURL_! Doh! http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php